# Android change position of textview on runtime

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I got 3 textviews which i want to move on swipe. How do i change position of a textview thats in a relative layout on runtime?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get it's layout params and set left, top, right and bottom and set this layout params to your textview.

Comment: Cannot seem to achieve the equivalent of android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" this way..?

Comment: above I've explain how to move a textview at runtime. if you want additional rules of arrangement, you may add rules to layout params. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: Ya thanks, i needed the addRule method. However, i perform my swipe, then change the elements align. But the align makes it flicker for a milli second which is annoying. Got any tips about that?